# Does the w3c.org site have documentation on "select"?

Tags: select, xpath, w3c

I cannot work out where this doco might be - i'm assuming they *do* have something on it. I realise this is a *dead* simple question, but no amount of searching is bringing this up for me.

Bing/DuckDuck etc search cannot find anything particularly relevant, and the only w3c.org links I followed went to "functions", which apparently "select" isn't.

**EDIT** (Apologies for ambiguity) I am looking for the definition of something along the lines of :

```
<xsl:variable name="variableName" select="some/path/here" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "select"? Do you have an example? Because "select" can mean a whole lot of different things - XPath expressions are often called "XPath selectors" for example, because they select elements.

Answer (score 3):

That is an [XSLT variable](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#variables). Like many other XSLT elements, it has a `select` attribute that takes an XPath expression as a value. The value of this attribute just typically happens to be an XPath expression, but the attribute itself isn't directly related to XPath, so you won't find it documented in the [XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20).

Answer (score 0):

You code fragment is in XSLT, so the specification you want is either "XSLT 1.0" or "XSLT 2.0", which you can find very easily by using these as Google search terms. The value of the select attribute is an XPath expression, so you may also want the XPath 1.0 or XPath 2.0 specification; these can be found the same way.